# Instantiating Data.AVL module with different element types

Tags: module, standard-library, agda

The Agda documentation gives some example of how to use the `Data.AVL` module:

http://darcsden.com/abel/AgdaPrelude/browse/README/AVL.agda

In the examples, the module is instantiated once at import-time with arguments specifying the type of values stored in the trees, as well as an order for the key type.

How does one use AVL trees at different value types (e.g. both trees of strings and trees of numbers) in the same client module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the `Data.AVL` module and use the functions directly. This is quite inconvenient because anytime you use such function, you have to give it all the module parameters, which means you'd end up with code looking like:

```
open import Data.AVL
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Nat.Properties
open import Data.String
  using (String)
open import Relation.Binary

test-tree : Tree (λ _ → String)
  (StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder strictTotalOrder)
test-tree = empty (λ _ → String)
  (StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder strictTotalOrder)
```

---

Let's not go there. Instead, we'll exploit the fact that Agda can create and apply modules (even inside another module). Here's one (totally artificial, sorry) example:

```
module M (A B : Set) where
  f : A → B → A
  f x _ = x
```

We can create new module just by applying `M`:

```
module M′ = M ℕ
```

If we ask what is the type of `M′.f` (using `C-c C-d`, for example), we get `(B : Set) → ℕ → B → ℕ`. If you compare that with `M.f : (A : Set) (B : Set) → A → B → A`, you can see that `ℕ` was indeed substituted for `A`.

Also, by applying it fully:

```
module M″ = M ℕ String
-- or equivalently
module M″ = M′  String
```

we get the expected `M″.f : ℕ → String → ℕ`.

---

So, how do we apply it to `AVL`? At this point, you probably see what's going to happen next:

```
module AVL[ℕ,String] = Data.AVL (λ _ → String)
  (StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder strictTotalOrder)

module AVL[ℕ,ℕ] = Data.AVL (λ _ → ℕ)
  (StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder strictTotalOrder)
```

All stuff from `AVL[ℕ,String]` operates on trees where the key is `ℕ` and the value is `String`. And here's how you can use it:

```
tree₁ : AVL[ℕ,String].Tree
tree₁ = insert 42 "hello" empty
  where
  open AVL[ℕ,String]

tree₂ : AVL[ℕ,ℕ].Tree
tree₂ = insert 1 2 empty
  where
  open AVL[ℕ,ℕ]
```

Notice that I locally open the `AVL[ℕ,String]` and `AVL[ℕ,ℕ]` modules so that I don't have to write, for example, `AVL[ℕ,String].insert`. Without the intermediate module, it would look like:

```
tree₁ : _
tree₁ = insert 4 "hello" empty
  where
  open Data.AVL (λ _ → String)
    (StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder strictTotalOrder)
```

Which is still far better than using the functions directly.

---

We can go even further and use instance arguments:

```
open import Data.Vec

module AVL-Instance
  {k} {Key : Set k}
  {v} {Value : Key → Set v}
  {ℓ} {_<_ : Rel Key ℓ}
  {{isStrictTotalOrder : IsStrictTotalOrder _≡_ _<_}}
  = Data.AVL Value isStrictTotalOrder

ℕ-IsStrictTotalOrder : _
ℕ-IsStrictTotalOrder =
  StrictTotalOrder.isStrictTotalOrder strictTotalOrder

open AVL-Instance
  hiding (Tree)

open module AVL-Type {k v} (Key : Set k) (Value : Key → Set v)
  = AVL-Instance {Key = Key} {Value = Value}
  using (Tree)

tree₁ : Tree ℕ λ _ → String
tree₁ = insert 4 "hello" empty

tree₂ : Tree ℕ (Vec ℕ)
tree₂ = insert 2 (0 ∷ 1 ∷ []) empty
```

This seems to work quite well, but my feeling is that this will be very fragile beyond simple examples.

To explain where my intuition is coming from, consider:

```
open import Data.Vec
  hiding (lookup)
open import Data.Maybe

tree₃ : Maybe (Vec ℕ 2)
tree₃ = lookup 2 (insert 2 (0 ∷ 1 ∷ []) empty)
```

What is the type of `empty`? It can very well be `Tree ℕ (Vec ℕ)`, `Tree ℕ λ _ → Vec ℕ 2` or something crazy like `Tree ℕ λ n → Vec ℕ (2 * n + 12)`. Instead of guessing, Agda will simply reject this definition and ask you to fill in more information:

```
tree₃ : Maybe (Vec ℕ 2)
tree₃ = lookup 2 (insert 2 (0 ∷ 1 ∷ []) (empty {Value = Vec ℕ}))
```

You've been warned. :)

Comment: Thanks, this is a great response! (I had supposed that some of these things were possible, but wasn't too confident understanding the error messages to make much headway with them!)

I ended up defining a new module `ℕ-AVL`, representing `Data.AVL` partially applied to use ℕ as the key type. I can instantiate this as needed with different codomain types.

I haven't yet played much with instance arguments, so I don't fully understand your comments regarding those. But I'll bear them in mind in future experimentation.

Comment: Refined question and tags to reflect the generality of your answer.